# Compare two separate documents VBA

Tags: vba, loops, excel

So what I want to do is have a macro in Workbook A that opens Workbook B and C.  After that it goes through column A of Workbooks B and C and where the two values are equal it takes the value from workbook C and pastes it into column A of workbook A.

I have written the below code, however it you think it's easier to do it another way please feel free to write your own one. Thank you and please help me :)

```
Sub ReportCompareAlta()
'
' ReportCompareAlta Macro
' Adds instances where column D is "ALTA"

    Dim varSheetA As Variant
    Dim varSheetB As Variant
    Dim varSheetC As Variant
    Dim StrValue As Variant
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim WbkA As Workbook
    Dim WbkB As Workbook
    Dim WbkC As Workbook
    Dim counter As Long

    Set WbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\Reporting\AH_MISSE_FEB2013.xls")
    Set WbkB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\Reporting\AH_MISSE_MAR2013.xls")
    Set WbkC = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\Reporting\ReportCompare.xls")
    Set varSheetA = WbkA.Worksheets("LocalesMallContratos")
    Set varSheetB = WbkB.Worksheets("LocalesMallContratos")
    Set varSheetC = WbkC.Worksheets("Sheet1")


    strRangeToCheck = "A1:IV65536"

    Debug.Print Now
    varSheetA = WbkC.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(strRangeToCheck) 'may be confusing code here
    varSheetB = WbkC.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(strRangeToCheck) 'may be confusing code here
    Debug.Print Now

    counter = 0

    For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)        
            If varSheetB(iRow, "B") = varSheetA(iRow, "B") & varSheetB(iRow, "B") <> "GERENCIA" & varSheetB(iRow, "B").Value <> "" & varSheetB(iRow, "D") = "ALTA" Then
                StrValue = ""
                varSheetB.Range("iRow:B").Select 
                Selection = StrValue
                ActiveSheet = varSheetC
                Range("A1").Select
                Selection.Offset(counter, 0).Value = StrValue
                counter = counter - 1

            Else
                MsgBox ("Done")
            End If         
    Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: So what does your code do? Does it work? If not, what does not work? Any error messages? I don't see a question here.

Comment: @OlleSjögren hey sorry to bother you but I was new to this site when I posted this question and as such didn't know the protocals, I tried to delete this question and start over before I found out there was editing so as my edit was answered in another thread I never edited or closed this. I was wondering if you could remove my down vote so I can get back on the path to being an upstanding and contributing member. Please and thank you

Comment: Sorry, the downvote is not from me so I can't do anything about it. I can give you an upvote though, for trying to do better. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some obvious errors as Mat Richardson points out, using the `&` is not equivalent shorthand for the `AND` operator, it's a concatenator, which is not likely what you want when you say:

`If varSheetB(iRow, "B") = varSheetA(iRow, "B") & varSheetB(iRow, "B") <> "GERENCIA" & varSheetB(iRow, "B").Value <> "" & varSheetB(iRow, "D") = "ALTA" Then`

Which brings me to another error:

`varSheetB` (and A, and C for that matter) are Variant/Array variables. You cannot index these by `iRow, "B"` because you cannot use a non-numeric index. Perhaps you mean (`iRow, 2`).

On a related note: `varSheetB.Range("iRow:B").Select` this will also fail, because you cannot `.Select` a Variant. This is **not** a Range variable. Further, `iRow:B` is not correct for *either* of a Variant array or a Range variable.  Also, at this point, `varSheetB` is no longer a `Worksheet` object variable.

Which brings me to probably the biggest error: You are using the variables `varSheetA`, `varSheetB`, and `varSheetC` to represent (at different times in this code) both a `Worksheet Object` and a Variant array of values.  This is confusing, and probably causing you the errors described above.  A variable cannot be both of these things at the same time, so you need to be treating your variants like variants when they are variants, and like worksheets when they are worksheets, or better yet: use worksheet variables for worksheets and variants for arrays, don't use the same variable for multiple purposes.

```
Sub ReportCompareAlta()
'
' ReportCompareAlta Macro

Dim varSheetA As Worksheet
Dim varSheetB As Worksheet
Dim varSheetC As Worksheet
Dim RangeToCheck As Range
Dim cl as Range
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim WbkA As Workbook
Dim WbkB As Workbook
Dim WbkC As Workbook
Dim counter As Long

Set WbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\Reporting\AH_MISSE_FEB2013.xls")
Set WbkB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\Reporting\AH_MISSE_MAR2013.xls")
Set WbkC = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\Reporting\ReportCompare.xls")
Set varSheetA = WbkA.Worksheets("LocalesMallContratos")
Set varSheetB = WbkB.Worksheets("LocalesMallContratos")
Set varSheetC = WbkC.Worksheets("Sheet1")


Set RangeToCheck = varSheetA.Range("A1:A65536") '## I change this because you only indicate you want to compare column A ##'

counter = 0

'## just loop over the cells in the range. ##'
'## This is not the most efficient, but it is the easiest ##'
For each cl in RangeToCheck  

    '## Do your comparison here, e.g: ##'
    '## Ignore cells where .Offset(0,3).Value = "ALTA" Or cl.Value = "" ##'
    If not cl.Offset(0,3).Value = "ALTA" Or Not cl.Value = vbNullString Then
        If Not cl.Value = varSheetB.Range(cl.Address).Value Then
           '## The values are not equal, so do something:
                varSheetC.Range(cl.Address) = "not equal"
           counter = counter+1
        Else:
           '## The values are equal, so do something else:
            varSheetC.Range(cl.Address) = "equal"
        End If
   End If
Next


MsgBox "Done! There were " & counter & " mismatch values", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least explain yourself. Anyways, good luck to you.

Comment: i'm unsure of the downvote, looks like a helpful answer to me.

Comment: I didn't downvote or at least didn't mean to? How can I un-down vote if I did so? Also it says I can't up vote until my "reputation" is better so as much as I'd like to compensate the people who helped me it appears I can't @DavidZemens

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the word 'AND' instead of the '&' symbol in your code.  Using '&' just concatenates the values, which will cause your if statement to fail.

Comment: Thank you... I changed the "&" to "and" but that line (the if statement) is still giving me the "error type mismatch" ... then I added .range before each "(iRow, "B") to fix this and now I'm getting the "error object required" on that same line (the if statement)... any ideas @Mat Richardson

Comment: @SeanConnecticut Yes. you're getting this error because (as I point out below) the `varSheetB` etc. are not range objects and/or you're not correctly indexing the arrays.

Comment: @DavidZemens Thank you that was very helpful.  I'm having a slight issue with putting the finishing touches on it. I want it to omit values where cell.offset(0, 3).value <> "ALTA" and cell.value = "" but do not know where to put that...thank you very much is there any way I can give you a recommendation or something like that because I'm very grateful but new to the site and not sure how it works.

Comment: @SeanConnecticut I made a revision to my answer below, adding another `If not cl.Offset(0,3).Value = "ALTA" Or Not cl.Value = vbNullString Then ... End If` to bracket the block where the comparison occurs. This should skip cells where `.Offset(0,3).Value = "ALTA"` or `.Value = ""`.

Comment: And if my answer has been helpful, you could give it an "upvote" :)